# Try-catch-finally order of execution appears to be random

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to understand how the `try-catch-finally` execution flow works. There are a couple of solutions from Stack Overflow users regarding their execution flow.

One such example is:

> ```
> try {
>     // ... some code: A
> } 
> catch(...) {
>     // ... exception code: B
> } 
> finally {
>     // finally code: C
> }
> ```
>
> Code A is going to be executed. If all goes well (i.e. no exceptions get thrown while A is executing), it is going to go to `finally`, so code C is going to be executed. If an exception is thrown while A is executed, then it will go to B and then finally to C.

However, I got different execution flows when I tried it:

```
try {
    int a=4;
    int b=0;
    int c=a/b;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    System.out.println("common");
}
```

I am getting two different outputs:

**First output:**

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at substrings.main(substrings.java:15)
lication.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
common
```

However, when I ran the same program for the second time:

**Second output:**

```
 common
    java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at substrings.main(substrings.java:15)
```

What should I conclude from this? Is it going to be random?

Comment: What ever the result, but it should not Random. Cross check.

Comment: different System streams produces improperly formatted output

Comment: Did you try to attach a debugger and step through the code?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`printStackTrace()` outputs to standard error. `System.out.println("common")` outputs to standard output. Both of them are routed to the same console, but the order in which they appear on that console is not necessarily the order in which they were executed.

If you write to the same stream in both catch block and finally block (for example, try `System.err.println("common")`), you'll see that the catch block is always executed before the finally block when an exception is caught.

Answer (score 7):

Exception's `printstacktrace()` method **source code**(defined in `Throwable` class)

```
public void printStackTrace() {
        printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
```

The formatting of output occurs because your are using standard output stream through `System.out.println`and exception occurs `System.err` stream

Try having a variable which will check exceptions and print in same error console if exception occurs :-

```
boolean isException = false;
try {
        int a=4;
        int b=0;
        int c=a/b;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       isException = true
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
       if(isException){
        System.err.println("common");
       }else{
        System.out.println("common");
       }
  }
```