# Why is there inconsistency in finally block/s execution with uncaught exception

Tags: java, exception, jvm, threadpool, try-catch-finally

I was recently asked in an interview on the sequence of execution of an exception case in java, where if the exception is not caught and propagated back to calling code, having finally blocks, then are the finally block statements printed ?
If they are then, are they printed before exception or after ?

I tried to run this scenario and found inconsistency in the outputs.

The code I tried is :

public class FinallyExecution {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

        FinallyExecution.divide(100, 0);

    }finally{
        System.out.println("finally in main");
    }

}

public static void divide(int n, int div){

    try{
        int ans = n/div;
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("finally of divide");
    }
}
```

}

And the inconsistent outputs are :

once:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at exceptions.FinallyExecution.divide(FinallyExecution.java:20)
    at exceptions.FinallyExecution.main(FinallyExecution.java:9)
finally of divide
finally in main`

and next:

`finally of divide
finally in main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at exceptions.FinallyExecution.divide(FinallyExecution.java:20)
    at exceptions.FinallyExecution.main(FinallyExecution.java:9)`

So what exactly is happening in this case ??
Is the JVM executing the finally blocks and then exiting with exception, or is it in the opposite sequence ?
In either case, why is the output inconsistent ?

Comment: Might be a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189792/try-catch-finally-order-of-execution-appears-to-be-random

Answer (score 1):

You are printing to `System.out` whereas the uncaught exception stacktrace is printed to `System.err`. You see both content in the console, but it is undefined in which order.

If you change your debug prints to use `System.err` then the order is consistent.

Comment: This explains the inconsistency. thank you